# CCAveneue payment intergration with WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ccavenue

I have searched lot about that implement CCAveneue payment intergration . i have also checked on CCAveneue websiter but did't get any information. if anybody have implemented CCAvenue in IOS then please provide any solution for that.
 * backend in JAVA

what i'm doing is just getting rsa key from server then what i have to do with that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Integration with CCAvenue was a difficult task. After long conversations with the support team and back-end teams, this is how we achieved integration with iOS app :

1. iOS app sends all the data (POST body key-value dictionary) to your backend server
2. Backend server redirects to the CCAvenue payment gateway by passing all the relevant information required by CCAvenue (please check CCAvenue integration guide for this)
3. User on iOS app fills in the payment details on the CCAvenue page and completes the payment
4. After payment completion, CCAvenue redirects to your backend server url (provided in the **"redirect_url"** key of POST data)
5. Here your backend server can process the payment response

*Now is the important step*

6. Your backend server after processing the response, should then redirect to a decided URL (YOUR_TRACKING_URL), which your iOS app will track to notify the completion of payment flow. This URL will be a server-client contract and must remain same in the iOS app.
7. In your iOS app, you can check this URL using UIWebView's delegate method as

   ```
   -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
   {
       if ([[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString:YOUR_TRACKING_URL])
       {
           // Payment flow complete. 
           // You can close the UIWebView here, or do whatever you want on payment completion
           // Do not allow redirect to this URL
           return NO;
       }

       return YES;
   }
   ```

Comment: Did the answer work for you? Or do you have any additional queries? You can accept / up-vote the answer if it helped you. :)